How do I set a voice variable that is today's date. For Google for meta?
Need to voice tape all the time want more flexibility or a good place to find lists of  variables list of commands Etc. Are there some standards? How's that stupid
Need to voice tape all the time want more flexibility. I'm just learning how to use whatever this is so thanks.
